# como puedo obtener el valor ASCII mayor a 128 en c#

Tags: c#

```
string text;
char c6 = (char)130;    
text = c6.toString();// el valor que retorna es = u0082    
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);// el valor que retorna es = 63
```

Answer (score 0):

El estándar ASCII usa 7 bits para codificar los carácteres. Es decir, posee 128 símbolos. 0 como mínimo y 127 como máximo. Tu valor cae fuera de ese rango y no puedes obtener su símbolo asociado, puesto que no tiene uno.

La forma que tienes de obtener lo que buscas es por medio de una codificación que comprenda tu valor. Puedes optar por [UTF8](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf8?view=net-6.0), [Unicode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=net-6.0) u otra.

Cita de la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.ascii?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> It uses replacement fallback to replace each string that it cannot encode and each byte that it cannot decode with a question mark ("?") character.

Esto quiere decir que si un valor no tiene un símbolo asociado, este será reemplazado por un signo de interrogación "?". O 63, el  número que estás obteniendo.

Este comportamiento también aparece documentado en otras clases de codificación de texto en .NET.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo su aporte, tengo una consulta como quito los valores en 0 que se han agregado en el bytes.

Comment: Valores en 0? A qué te refieres?

Comment: me devuelve esos valores en el bytes

Comment: [0] 0
[1] 130 en la variable datos

Comment: Sigo sin entender. A lo mejor si pasas el código pueda ayudarte.